# lock and get next n records from table in oracle

Tags: oracle, query-performance, query

I have a **oracle** table PHONE_NUMBER which has 2 columns PHONE and STATUS

```
PHONE_NUMBER 
PHONE STATUS
1     U
2     O
3     U
```

U stands for used , O is open/UnUSED .

in my input I will get n as input number , which signifies the number of phones I want to reserve(update status to U from O )

I want a query that will lock(something like SELECT FOR UPDATE) the any **n available** row (rows that are **not locked yet** and having status as O )

Constraints: Table has millions of Used and unsed phones

**comments:**

problem is i Want **n (input) rows** to be locked with a particular status . i.e i have to work with rownum

I will be getting multiple concurrent calls in my service with sqli_n as input number of records to select :
so

```
SELECT * FROM PHONE_NUMBER WHERE STATUS='O' and rownum<=:sqli_n FOR UPDATE ;
```

this query wont work for me it will select only first n rows and if the first n rows are locked in 1 call the next/concurrent call will be stuck /wait until the first call updates the status to Used .

for update no wait will fail the above query

for update skip lock will also not work with row num

Answer (score 1):

So, you have discovered that you can't do what you want; so you may want to do what you can by redesigning your process. One approach might be to introduce a new column, e.g. `session_id`, to indicate what application session, if any, is processing the row.

Each session will then start by atomically reserving a set of rows:

```
UPDATE phone_number SET session_id='<whatever>' 
WHERE status='O' AND session_id IS NULL AND ROWNUM<=:sqli_n;
COMMIT;
```

It will then do whatever it needs to do and finally release the reserved rows:

```
UPDATE phone_number SET session_id=NULL 
WHERE session_id='<whatever>';
COMMIT;
```

You'll likely need to revise indexes on this table.